# Getting objc_unretainedObject is unavailable: use a (_bridge id) cast instead when I use NSInputStream

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C and I am trying to have socket in my project and here is my code

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;
NSInputStream *iStream = objc_unretainedObject(readStream);
NSInputStream *iStream = objc_unretainedObject(readStream);
```

I am getting "objc_unretainedObject is unavailable: use a (_bridge id) cast instead" error @ line 3 and 4

Thanks in advance

Comment: "new to ObjC" and "objc_unretainedObject" don't really intersect.  You could blindly do what the compiler tells you and it might work.  But what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Replace objc_unretainedObject with (__bridge void *).. so:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;
NSInputStream *iStream = (__bridge void *)(readStream);
NSInputStream *iStream = (__bridge void *)(readStream);
```